# SQLiteOpenHelper error

Tags: android, sqlite

I read this http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html and now try to create my own simple example. For simplification reasons I don't have my own Adapter Class. When I try this

```
SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(this,"myDB.db3", null, 1);
```

in my applications onCreate method I see Ecplise telling me

```
Cannot instantiate the type SQLiteOpenHelper
```

I am not seeing what is basically different from the SDK tutorial (apart from that my call to the constructor is not wrapped in helper classes).

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLiteOpenHelper is an abstract class, you should inherit from it in order to instantiate one.

```
public class MyOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

...

}

MyOpenHelper dbHelper = new MyOpenHelper(...);
```